# EF7 consolidate many-to-many relationships

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following sample code:

```
public class User {
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks {get;set;}
}

public class Task {
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<User> Responsible {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<User> Accountable {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<User> Consulted {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<User> Informed {get;set;}
}
```

Now i can use the fluent API to create these relationships, however this creates a new table for each of these properties:

```
ResponsibleID | UserID | TaskID
-------------------------------
1             | 1      | 1

AccountableID | UserID | TaskID
-------------------------------
1             | 1      | 1

etc.
```

But i'd rather like to store them in a single table:

```
ResponsibilityID | UserID | TaskID | Responsibility
----------------------------------------------------
1                | 1      | 1      | Responsible
2                | 1      | 1      | Accountable
3                | 3      | 1      | Consulted
4                | 17     | 1      | Informed
```

the many-to-many class should look something like this:

```
public class UserTaskResponsibility {
    public ID {get;set;}
    public User User {get;set;}
    public Task Task {get;set;}
    public UserResponsibility Responsibility{get;set;}
}

public enum UserResponsibility {
    Responsible,
    Accountable,
    Consulted,
    Informed
}
```

Edit:
Using this class i changed the properties to

```
public class User {
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<UserTaskResponsibility> Tasks {get;set;}
}

public class Task {
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<UserTaskResponsibility> Responsible {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<UserTaskResponsibility> Accountable {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<UserTaskResponsibility> Consulted {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<UserTaskResponsibility> Informed {get;set;}
}
```

The Table created results in

```
ResponsibilityID | UserID | TaskID | Responsibility | TaskTaskID | TaskTaskTaskID | TaskTaskTaskTaskID
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                | 1      | 1      | Responsible    | Null       | Null           | Null              
2                | 1      | 1      | Accountable    | Null       | Null           | Null              
3                | 3      | 1      | Consulted      | Null       | Null           | Null              
4                | 17     | 1      | Informed       | Null       | Null           | Null
```

It adds an additional ID-Column for each reference of the collection. (Task for Responsible, TaskTask for Accountable and so on).

How can i tell these different Properties to refer to the same column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already answered on your question! Add UserTaskResponsibility class to your datacontext as new table and then change your models like this:

```
public class User {
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<UserTaskResponsibility> Links {get;set;}
}

public class Task {
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<UserTaskResponsibility> Links {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: When creating this Mapping EF adds a seperate ID-Column for each of the Tasks Properties to the table of the UserTaskResponsibility class. Your suggestion only works when using a single Collection of the same type. That said, it seems to miss a fluent-API configuration to refer to the same TaskID-Column since DataAnnotations are not available.

Comment: I think that you little confused. EF does all correctly (made several ID columns). You have at your variant some redundancy: column "Responsibility" with ID columns. If it is, for example, "Responsible" only TaskID will not be null, same way: "Accountable" - TaskTaskID, etc (not null already said about "Responsibility"). At my variant, yes, you have one collection, but kind of link you will specify at column "Responsibility" thats way it wiil be the equivalent of what you want.

Comment: The thing is, rather than hiding the necessary information to work with the object in a list which needs to be filtered over and over, i want the object to serve the necessary information in form of properties. Let me rephrase it: When I use your answer, i want 4 additional properties serving the filtered virtual ICollection<UserTaskResponsibility> Links {get;set;} collection. And writing this i am realizing that this should be implemented through an interface. Thank you very much!

Comment: I think that understood your idea. You will add four properties to `Task`, something like: `public List<UserTaskResponsibility> Responsible { get { return Links.Where(x => x.Responsibility == UserResponsibility.Responsible).ToList(); } }`. Yes, it is unexpected solution and gives you desired functionality, but don't forget to add `[NotMapped]` attribute to this properties to exclude them from ORM.